# Can I move my Downloads & Applications folder into my Dropbox Folder

Tags: macos, backup, finder

Please let me know if this question is better served elsewhere. To the extent that it is technical and potentially helpful to others, I'm hoping this post is okay (even though it is not code-related). I am having my Macbook Pro's battery replaced later today and want to make sure I don't lose too much in the case where they fuck up and have to wipe my computer (they said this is a possibility anytime a battery is replaced).

This is a snapshot of my Finder window, clicked on Home:

[image]
The `Documents` folder is nearly empty, as most stuff I would normally save there is in `Dropbox` instead. My question is - can i simply drag my `Applications`, `Downloads`, `Pictures`, `Music`, etc. folders **into** my `Dropbox` folder? I have the space (I have 1TB on Dropbox, with 850GB still available).

I'm simply not sure if dragging these entire main folders is okay? They have icons in the folders which (I think) means that they are specialty folders, and I'm worried that they won't behave properly if moved into the `Dropbox` folder.

Thanks in advance with this!!

Edit: I dont use iCloud, and only have 5GBs there, but let me know if simply purchasing a larger iCloud storage and backing up there is the more obvious way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can drag and drop those folders (Application, Documents, Music...) into the dropbox folder as a backup.

However, I would still recommend you select all the folders you want to copy first (Application, Documents, Music...) with maintaining the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key pressed while clicking. Then press  <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> and you will get the total number of files, and total size. It's a good indicator for how long it will take.

Also, I would recommend to drag and drop only one folder at a time, because they can be huge, so if something messes up during the copy, you can start over with only one folder, not everything.

---

Alternatively, for this kind of copy, I like to use the terminal, with the command `rsync`: it's more reliable, more lightweight and if something goes wrong, it can start back exactly from the last file copied. (But not everyone knows how to use it)

Here is what I would enter successively into the terminal:

```
rsync -avh ~/Documents ~/Dropbox/
rsync -avh ~/Downloads ~/Dropbox/
rsync -avh ~/Music ~/Dropbox/
rsync -avh ~/Movies ~/Dropbox/
rsync -avh ~/Pictures ~/Dropbox/
rsync -avh ~/Applications ~/Dropbox/
```

---

Also, beware that there are other files needed for your applications to be restored as they are (configuration, settings, cache...). They are mostly located into the `~/Library` folder, but this can become tricky to save everything "by hand", and that's why there are specialized backup programs like Time Machine.